# How can I grow air plants in an arid climate?

Tags: desert, tillandsia

I inherited several air plants (bromeliads probably in the genus [*Tillandsia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tillandsia)) from a friend. I know they are tropical in origin and lived in a greenhouse previously, but I live in a very arid climate. The plants seem to be drying out. How can I take care of them in this environment? Can I build a small greenhouse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I grow tillandsia in my house too. I just put the air plants into a driftwood. I didn't give them a greenhouse, but I think it is a good idea to keep the moisture. Also, please remember to install a pair of fans at the two sides of the tank. Air plant likes moisture but also good air flow.

Some growing tips from "[Tillandsia - Growing air plants](http://houseplants.about.com/od/bromeliad1/p/Tillandsia.htm)":

> Growing Conditions:
>
> Light: Bright light, but not direct sunlight. A south, east or west window is perfect. They can also be grown under fluorescent tubes.
>
> Water: Water 2 to 4 times a week with a mister. If your environment is dry, mist daily. Water until the plant is saturated.
>
> Temperature: Some varieties can withstand near freezing temperatures, but most will thrive between 70ºF and 85ºF. High humidity is a bonus.
>
> Support: Glue tillandsias to cork, coral, stone, or driftwood. Only a few varieties can adapt to soil.
>
> Fertilizer:Use a low-copper liquid fertilizer, diluted to 1/4 strength. Feed monthly.